# Method changes all instances of class inside list

Tags: python, list

In my script I have these classes:

```
class action:
  def __init__(self,ac_type,ac_date):
    self.ac_type = ac_type
    self.ac_date = ac_date

class user:
  actions = []
  def __init__(self,i_id):
    self.ivi_id = i_id
  def add(self,act):
    self.actions.append(act)
  def get_len(self):
    return len(self.actions)
```

I want to create list of "user" elements and add to some of theme actions. I do this in the following way:

```
for i in range(len(data_queue)):
  ind = users_id.index(data_queue[i].i_id);
  act = action(0,data_queue[i].added)
  users[ind].add(act)
```

But after running this I see that every action from data_queue was added to every user from users. This is wrong! What shall I change?

Comment: Your indention is wrong. You use both one and three spaces. Please fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is using class attribute which is shared by all instances of the class and the class itself.

Use an instance attribute instead:

```
class user:
    def __init__(self,i_id):
        self.ivi_id = i_id
        self.actions = []
    def add(self,act):
        self.actions.append(act)
    def get_len(self):
        return len(self.actions)
```

BTW, the code is using an index to iterate the sequence `data_queue`. Just iterate the sequence unless you really need the index.

```
for queue in data_queue:
    ind = users_id.index(queue.i_id)
    act = action(0, queue.added)
    users[ind].add(act)
```